# Cant able to set text property in UITextfield in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.2

I am new in IPhone developing...I am creating a application in XCode 4.2 . I am using navigation base application..In one view i put UITabbar with four UITabbarItem...which shows me four different views(i.e. FirstView,SecondView,ThirdView,FourthView)..From Firstview i am navigating another view(NavigativeView) ...On that view(NavigativeView) i have UITAbleview when i click on UITableviewcell it will navigating me on previous view(FirstView) with selected value.(I mean on main TabbarView)..On that view(FirstView) i have UITextField...I cant able to set that selected value in it...

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. And also providing a code about which you are talking about is a good practice. (don't forget to edit your code like code when pasting)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  When you *describe* your code, it is hard to help you.  When you **post** your code, we can do more to help you.  You can edit your question and paste in the code that you think is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could put an

```
@interface MyViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *text;
}
@end
```

instance variable in a controller object that controls your view.
Connect the controller's outlet in the interface builder to the UITextField.

When the user clicks on the UITableViewCell, fire an action that sets the value of the text field.

```
- (IBAction)setTextField:(id)sender {
   [text setText:[sender stringValue]];
   // code to give the focus to your FirstView ...
}
```

Or something like this. The text field in your FirstView should update automatically.

Comment: Having used XCode for OSX mostly, I'm not sure how to make a UITableCell fire an action though. The control does not seem to support action bindings.